# To show how something is terrible

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have the following sentence (with a noun substituted for "something"): "It's easy to show how something is terrible." This is awkward. I feel like there's a word or elegant phrase for "to show something is terrible", but I can't come up with it. Any ideas?

Comment: More context would help.

Comment: Your question lacks self-consistency. There is a difference between  'show ***how*** something is terrible' as given in your sentence and  'show something ***is*** terrible' as in the definition of your  single word. Please can you say which you require and edit the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: It depends what kind of a "thing" you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try words like:

- denigrate
- disparage
- criticize
- defame
- malign
- vilify
- condemn
- denounce

There are also phrases such as:

- highlight the faults of
- speak ill of
- cast aspersions on

Unfortunately, none of these provides a certain aspect of the tone of the your original: namely, a sense that the speaker is "in the right." When I read *"...to show how..."* I am interpreting that there is a certain amount of valid evidence in support of it. By contrast, if I *denigrate* or *denounce* something or someone, I could be doing so for any number of subjective or inappropriate reasons.

I think it might be interesting to consider substituting a more specific noun for *terrible* and using a construction such as:

> It's easy to show/prove the _____ of something.

For example,

> It's easy to prove the malice of prejudice.
>
> It's easy to highlight the injustice of torture.
>
> It's easy to demonstrate the blight of bigotry.
>
> It's easy to showcase the ills of hatred.

Answer (score 0):

"It is not difficult to expose (something's) malevolence."

"It is not difficult to expose malevolence."